# Postgres aggregate and pivot key, value pairs

Tags: arrays, postgresql-14, dynamic-pivot

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE locations (
    site_no integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name text,
    geom geometry(Point,4283)
);

CREATE TABLE location_attributes (
    site_no integer NOT NULL,
    qualifier text NOT NULL,
    value text NOT NULL
);
```

location_attributes contains a bunch features at most sites. Not all sites are present in location_attributes and some sites have multiple values of the same qualifier.

I'm trying to generate a wide, human-readable table showing each site_no with a column for each existing qualifier as below:

| site_no | name | qualifier1 | qualifier2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | value1.1; value1.2 | value4 |
| 2 | name2 | value2 | value5 |

See my wokring solution below. However, this is not very performant and becomes a lot slower with each added qualifier due to the joins.

```
WITH aggr AS (
SELECT
    site_no,
    qualifier,
    array_agg(value) as arr
FROM location_attributes
GROUP BY 1,2
)
SELECT
locations.site_no
, locations.name
, array_to_string(qualifier1.arr,'; ') as qualifier1
, array_to_string(qualifier2.arr,'; ') as qualifier2
FROM locations
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM aggr WHERE qualifier = 'qualifier1') as qualifier1   
ON locations.site_no = qualifier1.site_no
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM aggr WHERE qualifier = 'qualifier2') as qualifier2   
ON locations.site_no = qualifier2.site_no
```

There are a few problems I'd like to solve:

1. The number of qualifiers/keys can change over time. The query should get the qualifiers dynamically.
2. Re-write the query to be much more performant.
3. Which columns to index to improve performance further.

Thanks!